# Which cryptocurrencies are better suited to users with limited bandwidth?

Tags: synchronization, currencies, bandwidth

I'd like to try my hand at cryptocurrencies, but have limited bandwidth. Which cryptocurrencies are best suited to users such as me? Why?

Due to the high bandwidth costs, I expect cryptocurrencies to not be profitable for me, so my main priority here is to try my hand at a few of them without using up too much bandwidth. I'm not sure if this makes much difference to bandwith use, but I'd like to try my hand at mining and trading.

Comment: Please specify whether you want to use, mine, or learn about cryptocurrencies as this is a major aspect.

Comment: @UTF-8 All three I'm afraid. I'm interested in learning about them first, and I'd like to try my hand at mining them, but because I expect it to be unprofitable (in my case) I will probably just buy and sell as a casual user of cryptocurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from a few cryptocurrencies, including Bitcoin, most of them have very low exchange rates. So although you will find many such virtual currencies, it won't be profitable either way. And mining does not require bandwidth as such, it's only the blockchain synchronization which would be slower with a lower bandwidth. Mining is achieved by your machine and not the bandwidth.

If it's only the knowledge you wish to gain, then you can use the bitcoin testnet to mine test bitcoins, however trading testnet coins is not an option.

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of testnet. I guess I would still prefer to play with real working cryptocurrency. To that end, I should probably look for cryptocurrencies with small blockchains.

Comment: You can try zcash. It was launched on 28th October '16 and the blockchain size won't be as huge. However, one of the steps of installing requires downloading ~700MB of data. Also the Core apis are pretty similar to bitcoin core (it is basically a fork of the core bitcoin client)